# Removing Flutter footprints in release for Windows

Tags: windows, flutter, dll, flutter-release

When we build the flutter app in release mode for Windows, we will get a folder where we have the exe file, the dll, etc. But by looking at these files, I see many footprints of Flutter, e.g. one file is named as "flutter_windows.dll", many flutter packages are there with their exact names, flutter assets, etc.

My question is:

How can we hide such information as such it is not at least immediately obvious that Flutter has been used to make the exe file?